# Read text file into array using python

Tags: python, monkeyrunner

I have a textfile newfile.txt which contains following info:

```
http://filefirst.txt
http://filesecond.txt
http://filethird.txt
```

how should i read this file using python such that

```
line[0] = http://filefirst.txt
line[1] = http://filesecond.txt
...
```

and so on also i want to read this array variable in android activity using intents and bundle.

such that:

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
var1 = bundle.tostring();
```

`var1` should be equal to `http://filefirst.txt`

How should I go about doing this?

I am writing python script like this:

```
f = open('newfile.txt')
for line in iter(f):
    extravalue = {}
    extravalue['URIVALUE']=line
    print(line)
    print("value")
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)
device.startActivity(component=runComponent, extras=extravalue)
device.touch(10,350, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
f.close()
```

now i want to read extras in another activity.
I am doing it like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String uri = null;

        if (bundle != null && (uri = bundle.getString("URIVALUE")) != null)
        String[] path = uri.split(",");
```

In android i want to read such that path[0]=line[0],path[1]=line[1].
Currently what is happening it is storing only last line of txt file.

How can i modify the code above according to my requirements.

Regards
Mayank

Comment: Please format the question body properly, don't mix code and text.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to the first part:

```
with open('newfile.txt') as f:
    line = f.readlines()
```

I don't know what you mean by the second part, nor what `getIntent` does.

Also, while Kevin's answer is OK, he doesn't close the file.  The beauty of the `with open` is that it closes it automatically as soon as it's done reading it.

Comment: I concur - this is a cleaner version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to read the file into an array:

Assume that you have the following in a file named data.txt:

```
http://filefirst.txt
http://filesecond.txt
http://filethird.txt
```

This code will put it into an array:

```
f = open("data.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
print lines
```

Output:

```
['http://filefirst.txt\n', 'http://filesecond.txt\n', 'http://filethird.txt\n', '\n']
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass lines as extras to android activity and read lines from there,one at a time.I am writing pythin script as: